# What conditions must hold for the excerpt to be automatically displayed at /tags/[tagname]/info?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

If you look at the tags [3x3eyes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/3x3eyes/info) and [5-centimeters-per-second](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/5-centimeters-per-second/info) over at Anime.SE, you will notice that the former does not display the excerpt by default (there's a "show excerpt" link), while the latter does display the excerpt by default.

What conditions must hold for the excerpt to be automatically displayed?

Comment: I think it's a character minimum.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of experimentation suggests that this is indeed governed by a simple check for the length of the tag wiki.

In particular: if the HTML for a tag wiki is **at least 200 characters** in length, the excerpt will *not* be automatically displayed. If the HTML is **less than 200 characters** in length, the excerpt *will* be automatically displayed. Again, these lengths refer to the length of the baked HTML, not the length of the underlying markdown.

At the moment, [cordys-opentext](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cordys-opentext/info) (199 chars) and [gost28147](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gost28147/info) (200 chars) on Stack Overflow constitute a minimal pair that demonstrates this distinction.